# Passing varargs to plot() function

Tags: matlab, plot

I am writing a wrapper for `plot` that automates some tasks that I find myself doing frequently.

An example code snippet might look like

```
function myplot(x,y,varargin)
    plot(x,y,varargin{:})
    xlabel('x axis')
    ylabel('y axis')
end
```

I'm using Matlab's `varargin` to pass additional arguments to `plot`. However, I find that I might want to pass my own optional arguments in varargin. For example, I might want to write something like

```
>> myplot(1:10, 1:10, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2, 'legend', {'Series 1'})
```

to have the function automatically include a legend in the plot - that is, I want to be able to mix my own keyword arguments with the ones that you can supply to plot. Short of writing a full parser for my varargs, is there a way to do this simply and reusably in Matlab?

I've tried to use the `inputParser` object, but that would require me to manually add every possible additional argument to plot (and a default for it) which doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inputParser` may still be the best choice. You can construct the object for your additional arguments, and lump all the parameterName/parameterValue pairs that you want to pass to `plot` into `Unmatched`.

```
function myplot(x,y,varargin)

    parserObj = inputParser;
    parserObj.KeepUnmatched = true;
    parserObj.AddParamValue('legend',false); 
    %# and some more of your special arguments

    parserObj.parse(varargin);

    %# your inputs are in Results
    myArguments = parserObj.Results;

    %# plot's arguments are unmatched
    tmp = [fieldnames(parserObj.Unmatched),struct2cell(parserObj.Unmatched)];
    plotArgs = reshape(tmp',[],1)'; 


    plot(x,y,plotArgs{:})
    xlabel('x axis')
    ylabel('y axis')

    if myArguments.legend
       %# add your legend
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that you'll need some additional logic if you want to be able to handle the `linespec` argument, and if you want to be able to specify the axes handle as first input.

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks. I didn't realize you could keep the unmatched arguments. Annoyingly, handling the linespec is something I would very much like to do. Maybe it's time to just sit down and slog it out...

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: To handle linespec, I suggest that you put all the inputs into `varargin`. Then you can check input #1 for being a handle, if yes, you remove it from `varargin`, then you check for 1-2 numeric arguments and remove them, and then you check whether you're left with an even or odd number of elements in `varargin`. If it's odd, the first one is `linespec`.

Comment: Thanks - this is the solution I've gone with.

Comment: @FelipeG.Nievinski: Thank you for your suggestions (which were rejected by others). I prefer not to set e.g. the `@logical` requirement with the "addLegend" entry, since I tend to mix `false` and `0` when specifying inputs.

Answer (score 2):

To support the Linespec argument without interfering with input parser parameters that have a name of 4 characters or less (e.g., 'grid' or 'bins'), you should have a slightly more sophisticated way to check the validity of the Linespec argument than '@(x) ischar(x) && numel(x) <=4'. This check would return true also for 'grid' and 'bins', although they are no valid Linespec arguments.

The following function will return true only if a valid Linespec argument is entered:

```
function isls = islinespec(x)
isls    = false;

if ~ischar(x)
    return;
end

lineStyleSpecifiers     = {'--','-.','-',':'};
markerSpecifiers        = {'square','diamond','pentagram','hexagram','+','o','*','.','x','s','d','^','v','>','<','p','h'};
colorSpecifiers         = {'r','g','b','c','m','y','k','w'};

for oo=1:length(lineStyleSpecifiers)
    k = strfind(x,lineStyleSpecifiers{oo});
    if ~isempty(k)
        x(k:(k+length(lineStyleSpecifiers{oo})-1)) = [];
        break;
    end
end

for oo=1:length(markerSpecifiers)
    k = strfind(x,markerSpecifiers{oo});
    if ~isempty(k)
        x(k:(k+length(markerSpecifiers{oo})-1)) = [];
        break;
    end
end

for oo=1:length(colorSpecifiers)
    k = strfind(x,colorSpecifiers{oo});
    if ~isempty(k)
        x(k:(k+length(colorSpecifiers{oo})-1)) = [];
        break;
    end
end

if isempty(x)
    isls = true;
end
```

(Admittedly, the function could have been written more elegantly with regular expressions, but it does the trick.)

Example usage:

```
parserObj = inputParser;
parserObj.KeepUnmatched = true;
parserObj.AddParamValue('legend',false);
parserObj.AddParamValue('grid',true);
parserObj.addOptional('LineSpec','-', @(x) islinespec(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

To add support for LineSpec using the parser in a way that is unambiguous w/ param/val pairs, do:

```
function myplot(x,y,varargin)
    parserObj = inputParser;
    parserObj.KeepUnmatched = true;
    parserObj.AddParamValue('legend',false);
    parserObj.addOptional('LineSpec','-',@(x) ischar(x) && (numel(x) <= 4));
    %# and some more of your special arguments

    parserObj.parse(varargin{:});

    %# your inputs are in Results
    myArguments = parserObj.Results;

    %# plot's arguments are unmatched
    plotArgs = struct2pv(parserObj.Unmatched); 

    plot(x,y,myArguments.LineSpec,plotArgs{:})
    xlabel('x axis')
    ylabel('y axis')

    if myArguments.legend
       %# add your legend
    end
end

function [pv_list, pv_array] = struct2pv (s)
    p = fieldnames(s);
    v = struct2cell(s);
    pv_array = [p, v];
    pv_list = reshape(pv_array', [],1)';
end
```